# How to delete irrelavent roads and show desired route in GoogleMaps? What's the corresponding API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I want to customize the Google maps to delete the irrelevant roads of our project and just want to show specific roads we want. Also, about the label of the places, could I select the place I want to put label on instead of showing all the places? The platform is just WEB.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm you can't 'delete roads' in Google Maps. The best you can do is style it. Play around with

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

You have 3 choices of roads - Highway, Arterial and Local. Feel free to style each as you see fit, or hide it altogether.